# primary foreign key display in html table

Tags: php, mysql

ok here is it. i have two tables: products and warehouse

product table consist of (pid(primary),pname,pcolor) while my 
    warehouse table has (pid(primary foreign key=> products table),
    date_delivered,quantity).

my question is can i display the warehouse table with pid,pname,pcolor,date_delivered and quantity since my primary key in warehouse table is the pid from products table? can i use join with these? if so how?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM product
INNER JOIN warehouse
ON product.pid = warehouse.pid
```

Here an [Inner Join](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp) is used.

Comment: he also needs the fields from the warehouse table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.pid, pname, pcolor, date_delivered, quantity 
    from products a, warehouse b 
    where a.pid = b.pid;
```